# Uma função que leia apenas o ultimo número inteiro escrito em um arquivo de texto e retorne?

Tags: c, arquivo, texto

```
 FILE * save;

int funcao () {

int d;

char linha[100];

save = fopen ("light.txt" , "r");

if (save == NULL) {

    printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");

    return -1;

}

else {

    while (!feof){

         fgets(linha, 99, save);

    }

}

sscanf(linha, "%d", &d);

printf("\n%d\n", d);

return d;

}
```

Comment: É um arquivo do tipo texto ou binário? A quantidade de linhas é predeterminada ou não? O tamanho de cada linha é fixo ou variável? Existem múltiplos números em cada linha? Pode variar de linha para linha?

Comment: Olá. É um arquivo de texto, a quantidade de linhas aumenta diariamente e cada linha tem tamanho variável. Só haverá um número inteiro em cada linha [1, 30]. Preciso que a função leia qual é o último número, na última linha e retorne ele.

Comment: Você sabe que raciocínio seguiria e só tem problemas com o uso das funções de i/o? Ou sua dúvida é de fato o raciocínio do problema, não as funções em si da biblioteca?

Comment: Eu sou iniciante ainda. Não conheço muitas funções para manipular arquivos e não sei quais poderiam me ajudar a fazer o que quero. Acho que ambos raciocinio e as funções.

Comment: Afinal o código acima funcionou ou não? Se não funcionou qual o resultado obtido e qual o esperado? Note que com a alteração não tem mais sentido a referência a `fseek`.

Comment: O código da descrição não funcionou, nem o da resposta anonima. Aparentemente o vetor linha não ta lendo o finalzinho da ultima linha em que tem o número e o fscanf ta lendo algo que não sei da onde vem.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se é algo do tipo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE * save;
    char linha[100];
    int d;
    save = fopen ("light.txt" , "r");
    if (save == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        while (fgets(linha, 100, save) != EOF )
            ;
        fclose(save);
    }
    sscanf(linha, "%d", &d);
    printf("\n%d\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```